# Excel 2013 Sorting alphanumerics with spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, sorting

I have a list of Hebrew dates that looks like this (actually over 200 entries, of course):

- Tammuz 5
- Nissan 7
- Tevet 10
- Tevet 10
- Tishrei 11
- Av 2
- Adar 1
- Adar I 21
- Tammuz 14
- Tammuz 25
- Tammuz 23
- Iyar 10

I would like to be able to sort them by the numbers within each month, but correctly, not 1, 10, 11, 2, 21, etc, which is all I've been able to get.  The answers I have found on the web for sorting alphanumeric data seem only to work when the data has no spaces.

I'm not worried about getting the months in the right order; alphabetical is fine. I just need to see the dates in numerical order without having to retype each entry.

Comment: Laura, if your entry "Adar I 21" is a typo (i.e. should not have the letter I in it), you can use this formula to extract the number: "=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1))" and then sort on that column.  You may need to format that column as Number.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data starts with A1, this is a way to do what you are asking, although it seems that there should be a much easier way:

- Populate B1 with `=TRIM(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2))` and copy it down.
- Populate C1 with `=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2))*1)` and
  copy it down.
- Select B1 to the last entry in column C (C12 using your sample data) and Copy.
- Select E1 and Paste Special, Values only.
- Select E1 to the last entry in column F and **Custom Sort** column E from `A to Z` and column F from
  `smallest to largest`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Clif, it worked! (and no, Adar I was not a typo, so I am happy to see that it was preserved).

Comment: You are welcome and thank you for the feedback and the acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a couple of options.

Either change the data so that the dates have leading zeros so that they sort correctly on their own without intervention.

Alternatively, create a separate sort column where you replace single numbers with their counterparts with the leading zero. You might find it easiest to create 2 new columns, splitting the full date into its two components and making the second column a number as @BillOer suggests in his comment. Then you can apply a sort to the 2 columns to keep the month sorted first then the date.

Note that, since Hebrew seems to have some month names with spaces such as "Adar I" (if I've interpreted things correctly), you might find yourself doing a fairly complex formula to replace the spaces in month names with a unique character ">" for example. Then you can find the split between the month and the number, finally replace the ">" with a space in the column with the month name.